# How to show all calendars at startup on Outlook 365 using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I use Outlook 365 on windows 10.
There are three calendars in the "My Calendars" group.
I would like to show all calendars at startup with the default calendar, Calendar 1, active using VBA.
To do this, I use the following VBA code, but there are two problems.

One problem is that a part of the code is redundant, which makes it time-consuming.
By default, only Calendar1 in My Calendars group is visible after startup.
To show all calendars, the code makes Calendar2 and Calendar3 visible.
After running these commands, Calendar3 is active.
To activate Calendar1 after startup, the code makes Calendar1 invisible and then visible.

I think, instead of this, it's an efficient way to use the command corresponding to check the checkbox of "My Calendars" in the navigation pane.
But I don't know how to do this.

The other problem is that, after startup using this macro, I can't switch day view and month view by shortcut keys, Cntl+Alt+1 and Cntl+Alt+2.
I think the way to check the check of "My Calendars" solves this problem
because I can switch these views by the shortcut keys when I manually check the checkbox.

So could you tell me the way to solve these problems?
Thank you in advance.

```
Private WithEvents g_Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set g_Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items

setupInitialDisplayCalendars
End Sub

Public Sub setupInitialDisplayCalendars()

Dim navModCal As CalendarModule
Dim navGroup As NavigationGroup

Set navModCal = ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
Set navGroup = navModCal.NavigationGroups.Item("My Calendars")

If Not (navGroup Is Nothing) Then
navGroup.NavigationFolders.Item("Calendar2").IsSelected = True
navGroup.NavigationFolders.Item("Calendar3").IsSelected = True
navGroup.NavigationFolders.Item("Calendar1").IsSelected = False
navGroup.NavigationFolders.Item("Calendar1").IsSelected = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at [Select Multiple Calendars in Outlook](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/select-multiple-calendars-outlook/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NavigationFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationfolders) object can be used to display calendars listed on the navigation page in Outlook.

```
Sub SelectCalendars()
    Dim objPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As Outlook.CalendarModule
    Dim objGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder
    Dim objCalendar As Folder
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    DoEvents
    
    Set objCalendar = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    
    With objModule.NavigationGroups
        Set objGroup = .GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olMyFoldersGroup)
    End With

    For i = 1 To objGroup.NavigationFolders.Count
        Set objNavFolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
        Select Case i

        ' Enter the calendar index numbers you want to open
            Case 1, 3, 4
                objNavFolder.IsSelected = True
             
        ' Set to True to open side by side
                objNavFolder.IsSideBySide = False
            Case Else
                objNavFolder.IsSelected = False
        End Select
    Next

' set the view here

    Set objPane = Nothing
    Set objModule = Nothing
    Set objGroup = Nothing
    Set objNavFolder = Nothing
    Set objCalendar = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

To change calendar folder view (day/week/month) you can use the view object:

```
Dim objViews As Views
 Dim objView As View
 
Set objViews =  Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Views
 Set objView = objViews.Item("Calendar")
  With objView
      ' Set the calendar view to show a
      ' single day.
      .CalendarViewMode = olCalendarViewDay
  End With

 objView.Apply
```

The [CalendarView.CalendarViewMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.calendarview.calendarviewmode) property returns or sets an [OlCalendarViewMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olcalendarviewmode) that determines the current view mode of the [CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.calendarview) object.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your way is almost same for that of my code. After running your code, calendar 1, 3 and 4 are shown but calendar 4 is active. That is the problem for me. I want to show all calendars "with the default calendar (calendar 1) is active" at start up. So I wrote the above my code.  And your second code made my Outlook calendar freezing somehow.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Why do you need to change view?

Comment: I would like to show all calendars with the default calendar (calendar 1) is active and with month view at start up and after that I would like to switch month view and week view by short cut keys, Cntl+Alt+1 and Cntl+Alt+2. My code can do the first one but little bit time consuming and I cannot do the second one.      I think the way to check the check of "My Calendars" solves these problems But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: A while ago, I found that after running my code and then I click two times on my calendar, I can switch between two views. This is almost ok for me. But I would like to know more efficient solution.

Comment: I will supplement my explanation. I would like to show all calendars with the default calendar (calendar 1) is active at start up because I mainly use the default calendar so that is time efficient for me.